# Can I do this kind of parallel computing on GPU?

Tags: ios, matrix, opengl-es, gpu

I have a M*N integer matrix, which I need to traverse and compute this for every element M[i][j]:

```
The integer which appears most often in the submatrix from (i-k,j-k) to (i+k, j+k).
```

So the result is a matrix with each cell being the dominant number around [i,j] in original matrix.

The matrix could be very large, and I need to do this operation in a tight loop, so I want to minimize the operation time by parallel computing.

I know GPU is good at matrix multiplication, but it looks like this cannot be reduced to a simple matrix multiplication. (or can it?)

Is it possible to compute each cell in parallel on GPU? And if it is, I want to implement this in iOS, what programming interface should I use, Metal? OpenGL?

Comment: the programming interface to do GPU calculation that are not graphics related is call https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate.  There is lots of matrix stuff at https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/blas.  For your particular question I don't know if there are functions that do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! How does `accelerate` compare to `Metal`? Is one based on another, which one is more high-level and easier to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this computation on GPU.

**Metal** seems to be for both graphical and general purpose computation. So you should be able to use it for your needs (here is an article introducing it: http://memkite.com/blog/2014/12/15/data-parallel-programming-with-metal-and-swift-for-iphoneipad-gpu/)

**[Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate)** can also fit our needs.

Hope this help.